# Ruby on Rails - Counter cache doesn't work on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, counter-cache

I have added `counter_cache` to `punching_bag` gem. Everything works fine in `Development ENV`, but in `Production ENV` it doesn't do what it suppose to to.

I can see that `punches_count`column is added into my `posts` table, but it doesn't `increment` the column.

Why this is happening and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Post` model add following:

`attr_accessor :punches_count`

`has_many :punches`